# how to redirect subdomain to main domain using htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I have canada website, have two version of website `ca.domainname.com` and `canada.domainname.com`. I want 301 permenant rediret `ca.domainname.com` all website to `canada.domainname.com` through htaccess.tried below code

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^CA\.domainmae\.com$   [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://canada.domainmae.com  [L,R]
```

Answer (score 1):

Changing

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^CA\.domainmae\.com$   [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://canada.domainmae.com  [L,R]
```

to

```
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://canada.domainmae.com  [L,R=301]
```

should work. Put that in the htaccess file in te root folder of `ca.domainmae.com`

If you want to be redirected to the corresponding url on the new website you can use:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://canada.domainmae.com/$1  [L,R=301]
```

Comment: can we redirected inner pages with above rule like 
http://canada.domainname.com/AB/dkskdsldkls/dfjdkfjdkfjdkfjdk/ct_1000968588 to http://ca.domainname.com/AB/dkskdsldkls/dfjdkfjdkfjdkfjdk/ct_1000968588